# Making a Complicated Ragged List Simpler and Regular

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a large list that has two elements in odd numbered positions at level 1.  At level 2 the first element is not a string {{"[An Integer]"}} (usually less than 15 seemingly stored at level 3), whereas the second element is a long multi-line string that
requires splitting.  Together these two part sublists form a logical record.  At even numbered positions at level 1 there is only a single value nested containing an {{"@"}}.

I would like to delete those elements that are {{@}}, and after deleting the left and right square brackets around the integer value and then splitting the sublists at the first "\n"'s so that the final result is close to a simple list of lists with just 2 levels that I can then map to suitable headers. Although not evident in this subsample of the data, the first "\n" which separate two codes that may not be the same.

The elements with Null strings should not be a problem, since they can easily be removed by removing a column from the dataset or by skipping the associated part at the appropriate position in level 2 sublists prior to threading. Note that the list, which has 2415 records is ragged and in some cases does not include "Old Name: ","Remarks:", "Other Abbrev.:" or "WWW Sites:", some combination of these, or all four. To address this I suspect will have to parse using functions of different signature, and by checking the length of the sublists and by adding elements via padding as required to level 2.

I've tried a variety of approaches, flattening a different levels, trying various permutations of DeleteCases, Join, StringSplit, /. and various functional constructs, but can not figure out how to get the current list structure closer to what I want.  I think my efforts are getting confused by the substrings "\\n" and "\n" that appear at different levels and the variously missing components.

Listed below are is the InputForm first 14 "records", each of which can be seen using Part (ie r4[[1]] r4[[2]], ... r4[[14]] or should be, if I have cut and pasted correctly.

```
        r4 = 
        {
        {{"[ 1 ] "}, {"ABAM-I\\nABAM-I", "", "Cole\\[CCedilla]\\ 
        [ATilde]o \\\nde Peixes do Acervo Biol\\[OAcute]gico da Amaz\\ 
        [OHat]nia Meridional, Sinop, \\\nState of Mato Grosso, \
        Brazil.\\n  Other Abbrev.: LIT. Country: Brazil"}}, {{"@"}}, {{" 
        [ 1 ] "}, {"ABE\\nABE", "", "Tokiharu Abe Collection.\\n  
        \\\nCountry: Japan\\n  Remarks: Personal collection of \
        Tokiharu Abe; some types \\\nwere housed at the Tokyo fish 
        market. Collection will be (or has been) \\\ntransferred to 
        ZUMT."}}, {{"@"}}, 
        {{"[ 1 ] "}, {"ACAP\\nACAP", "", 
        "Aquaculture Center of Aomori \\\nPrefecture, Higashitsugaru, 
        Aomori Prefecture, Japan.\\n  Alternative Name: \\\nAomoriken 
        Suisan Zoshoku Senta. Country: Japan"}}, {{"@"}}, 
        {{"[ 1 ] "}, {"AFAQ\\nAFAQ", "", "Queensland Amateur Fishing 
        \\\nClubs Association Inc., Australia.\\n  Old Name: Amateur 
        Fisheries Association \\\nof Queensland. Country: \
        Australia\\n  WWW sites: Main site: \\\nhttp://www.qafca.org.au/   
        \\n  Remarks: Most specimens transferred to \\\nQueensland 
        Museum (QM), Brisbane."}}, {{"@"}}, 
        {{"[ 1 ] "}, {"AFDZ\\nAFDZ", "", "Department of Zoology, 
        \\\nFaculty of Science, University of Damietta, Egypt.\\n  
        Country: Egypt"}}, {{"@"}}, 
        {{"[ 1 ] "}, {"AFY\\nAFY", "", "Agust\\[IAcute]n \\\nFern\\ 
        [AAcute]ndez-Y\\[EAcute]pez collection.\\n  Country: 
        Venezuela\\n  Remarks: \\\nPersonal collection; at least some of 
        this \
        collection is at SCN, Venezuela. \\\nSome extant material at 
        FMNH, MBUCV. SCN (now MHNLS)"}}, {{"@"}}, 
        {{"[ 1 ] "}, {"AHF\\nAHF", "", "Allan Hancock Foundation, 
        \\\nUniversity of Southern California, California, U.S.A.\\n  
        Country: U.S.A.\\n  \\\nWWW sites: Main site: \
        http://www.ahcfoundation.org/   \\n  Remarks: Types 
        \\\nincorporated into the LACM collection. Non-type collection 
        still at AHF."}}, {{"@"}}
        }
```

**Can anyone help me to get this list in or closer to the desired form?**

**(Hints toward a partial solution welcome!)**

Desired is: (2415+1)/2, 10 element sublists {Numeric value, Code1, Code2 (possibly same or different from Code1), Null String, Museum Name (sometimes including location),Old Name(s), Other abbreviations, Country, Websites, Remarks}.